# Bind to attributes in prototypically inherited scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to create a directive, with a prototypically inherited scope (i.e. *scope=true*), but also set up scope binding to attributes, similar to following when setting up an isolated scope:

```
scope = {
'varname':'=attrname'
}
```

My current solution is to set *scope=true* and set up the binding to the attributes along the following lines in the *link* function:

> scope.$watch(element.attr('attrname'), function(val) { scope.varname =
>   val; }); // watch changes scope.varname =
>   scope.$eval(element.attr('attrname')); // initialize

Although it does the trick it doesn't seem to be very elegant. What approach do you suggest?

I find it surprising angularjs seems to expect that in a directive you wouldn't need attribute binding when setting up a new inherited scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you mean and I agree with you.  It would be nice if Angular provided a convenient framework for a directive to set-up two-way model binding between a parent scope variable and a child scope variable and still support prototypical scope inheritance.

To achieve the same effect as the following with isolated scope:

```
 scope = {'varname':'=attrname'}
```

you can set up the two-way model binding within your directive's link function:

```
scope: true,
link:  function(scope, element, attr) {
     // when attrname changes in parent scope, update varname in current scope
     scope.$parent.$watch(attr.attrname, function(newVal) {
          scope.varname = newVal;
     });

     // when varname changes in current scope, update attrname in parent scope
     scope.$watch('varname', function(newVal) { 
          scope.$parent[attr.attrname] = newVal;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this code in the directive link function:

```
 var yourVar = $parse(attrs.attrName)(scope);  // Parse the attribute with a specific scope context
```

You'll then pass attributes like you did with isolated scope directive, while still being able to use a prototypically inherited scope.

If you find yourself wanting to observe the changes of the variable, then I believe that you should use isolated scope and not inherited. It's still doable by observing attribute changes like suggested below, however I don't think it's the best practice. (I don't have much to support that claim, only intuition, so pick whatever you think is best)

If you want to know how $parse works, you can find more info here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

Please let me know in the comments if you need a plunker also, or if you got the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not entirely clear to me how this:
- sets the evaluated expression on the inherited scope
- keeps watching the attribute value and updates the value on the inherited scope

Answer (score 0):

Given what you want to achieve I consider your solution totaly valid. You could still improve your code if you use `$scope.$observe()` instead of `$scope.$watch()`:

```
scope.$observe('attrname', function(val) {
    scope.varname = $parse(val)(scope);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll dig into the differences between your and my solution. Do you think solving the problem in this way has performance implications vs. the way angular handles attribute binding internally in the normal (isolated scope) scenario?

Comment: I don't see any obvious performance issues with that solution. However, I can not garantuee, there may be no difference to how angular would handle the binding itself.

Comment: this is an interesting solution. I'd like to know how it works, not sure I understand

Comment: Actually using observe doesn't work (perhaps only when the attribute itself changes, but it doesn't trigger changes when the attribute refers to a changing variable). Makes sense after I think about it.

Comment: you're absolutely right. `$observe` only triggers when the attributes change. So you have to `$watch` the expression in the attribute and my suggested solution does not work.